# Estimation of the average length of repeated symbols in a sequence

Tags: probability, statistics

I would like to solve the following problem and I am not sure where should I begin with.

A sequence of $n$ symbols is denoted by $S$, where each symbol can take on values from a set $V$ of cardinality $\mid V\mid$ with equally probability. Furthermore, assume that in the sequence $S$ some symbols might be consecutively repeated. This can be indicated by the value 1 whenever repetitions occur and 0 otherwise. For example, consider the following sequence: $S = \{A, B, B, C, B, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, A\}$, then the corresponding indication of repetition is represented by $R = \{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0\}$.

I would like to estimate the average length of repeated symbols and a confidence interval for this estimation for e.g. the percentile $0.95$.

I would be very glad if someone could give me a hint how t solve this...Thanks!!

Comment: Hello! It is not clear to me what you mean by "average length of repeated symbols". For the example you give, do you mean the average of 1, 2, and 3 (i.e., 2)? That is, do you mean the average of the lengths of runs of 1's in your binary sequence?

Comment: Or do you mean the average of 2, 3, 4 (the lengths of runs of repeated symbols in your $S$)?  Can you give an example of how your calculate the average length of repeated symbols from your $R$?

Comment: I meant the first one, actually. I think it might ne necessary to chunk the sequence into smaller ones and then to compute the average length of repeated symbols...